# Is there an SDK out for Windows Run Time (WinRT)?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there some kind of SDK out for WinRT.? Can we develop applications for it now?

Is VS2010 usable for developing or will some other IDE be shipped? Also, is C++ necessary to develop performance-oriented apps in WinRT, or will the C# applications give equivalent performance? Can development be done on Win7?

I am curious about this because I missed out when WPF was released and I don't want to miss out on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview is also available on [Subscriber Downloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx) if you *do* have a subscription, and it includes the WinRT SDK and runs on Windows 7 and other operating systems.  So you can build it and debug it, but you still have to run your code on a Windows 8 machine.

Performance-wise, WinRT doesn't change the guidance for whether to use native code.  The APIs will behave near identically regardless of what language you choose, so make the decision between C++ and C# just as you would today.

Comment: Thanks of the up .... learing VC++ would have been a challange for me... i feel real comfortable with c#

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [Windows Dev Center](http://dev.windows.com/) where you can download a copy of Windows 8, complete with all the new tools for developing for it.

Comment: "Note that only BUILD conference attendees and MSDN subscribers can currently acquire the tools necessary to build Metro style apps"--- thats not fair

Comment: "No development" is a strong term - you could still write the code on a Windows 7 box, but you wouldn't be able to build or debug it on Windows 7 at present.

Comment: First link on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229516 is the download for the ISO including the dev tools (no subscription required)